# Buscar en diferentes campos de tabla MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy implementado un buscador, pero quiero que se pueda buscar ingresando distintos valores. Me explico: tengo una tabla que tiene 3 campos `nombre_alumno`, `rut_alumno` y `apellido_alumno`, lo que quiero es que al ingresar un número despliegue valores del campo rut o si tiene letra que busque en el campo nombre o apellido y los muestre, hasta el momento tengo esto en el lado del servidor (en PHP):

```
  $buscar = $_POST['b'];

  if(!empty($buscar)) {
        buscar($buscar);
  }

  function buscar($b) {
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '12345678');
        mysql_select_db('colegio_pool', $con);

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE nombre_alumno LIKE '%".$b."%' LIMIT 10" ,$con);

        $contar = @mysql_num_rows($sql);

        if($contar == 0){
              echo "No se han encontrado resultados para '<b>".$b."</b>'.";
        }else{
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $nombre = $row['nombre_alumno'];
            $rut = $row['rut_alumno'];

            echo "<a><p class='alert alert-info' style='text-align:center'>".$nombre."</p></a>";

        }
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para implementar lo que quiero?

Answer (score 3):

No se si te he entendido muy bien, pero creo lo que necesitas es que cuando captures por `$_POST` la variable con la que vas a filtrar te busque en las 3 columnas de tu tabla:

- `nombre_alumno`
- `rut_alumno`
- `apellido_alumno`

Si es eso utiliza esta consulta:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE nombre_alumno LIKE '%".$b."%' OR rut_alumno LIKE '%".$b."%' OR apellido_alumno LIKE '%".$b."%' LIMIT 10" ,$con);
```

De esta forma busca coincidencias que estén en varias columnas.

**Editado**

No he podido probar este código ya que la versión de php que tengo es la 7.0 y las funciones de mysql_connect estan obsoletas y no he podido instalarme una versión más antigua.

Prueba con esto:

```
<?php
$buscar = $_POST['b'];

if(!empty($buscar)) {
    buscar($buscar);
}

function buscar($b) {
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '12345678');
    mysql_select_db('colegio_pool', $con);

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE nombre_alumno LIKE '%".$b."%' OR rut_alumno LIKE '%".$b."%' OR apellido_alumno LIKE '%".$b."%' LIMIT 10" ,$con);

    $contar = @mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if($contar == 0){
            echo "No se han encontrado resultados para '<b>".$b."</b>'.";
    }else{
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $nombre = $row['nombre_alumno'];
        $rut = $row['rut_alumno'];
        $apellido = $row['apellido_alumno'];
        if (strpos($nombre, $b)>=0)
            echo "<a><p class='alert alert-info' style='text-align:center'>nombre_alumno:".$nombre."</p></a>";
        else if (strpos($rut, $b) >= 0) 
            echo "<a><p class='alert alert-info' style='text-align:center'>rut_alumno: ".$rut."</p></a>";
        else if (strpos($apellido, $b) >= 0)
            echo "<a><p class='alert alert-info' style='text-align:center'>apellido_alumno: ".$apellido."</p></a>";

    }
}
```

Comment: entiendo, pero después como muestro el resultado?

Comment: en la parte de mysql_fetch_array?

Comment: Quieres que te muestre la coincidencia de columna con la busqueda?

Comment: si, eso es lo que quiero

Comment: He editado y como te pongo el código no esta probado, con las funciones mysqli se puede poner el código para que quede mejor, te recomiendo que les eches un ojo, ya que son las que se utilizan en php7.0

Answer (score 2):

Para implementar los que deseas debes usar `CONCAT()` en tu `WHERE`, esto permitirá agrupar los valores y hacer una sola comparación.

Tu consulta quedaría así:

```php
 $consulta = " 
       SELECT * FROM alumno 
       WHERE CONCAT(rut_alumno,nombre_alumno,apellido_alumno) LIKE '%".$b."%'
       LIMIT 10";
 $sql = mysql_query($consulta,$con);
```

opcionalmente  puede agregar este fragmento de código para resaltar la palabra buscada y tu usuario sepa de donde se obtuvo la coincidencia, al inicio de tu archivo copia la funcion:

```php
function resalta($b,$valor){
   return count(pre_split($b,$valor)) > 1 ? implode( pre_split($b, $valor) ," <strong> ".$b." </strong> ") : $valor;
}
```

Con el código anterior podrías mostrar los resultado así:.

```php
 while(...){
   echo "<a>".resalta($b,$row['rut_alumno']).", ".resalta($b,$row['nombre_alumno']). "</a>";
 }
```

y el resultado se veria asi.

> 123, JUANA M**ARI**A RINCON B**ARI**TA

Te explico un poco el código: la función `pre_split` divide el valor de `$nombre`, si se divide en mas de 1 pedaso quiere decir que `$b` se encuentra dentro de nombre. Ejemplo `$b = "ari"` entonces `"maria"` se divide en `"m" y "a"` , luego con `explode()` uno la palabra de nuevo pero con `<strong></strong>` en medio, quedando así `"m" . "<strong>ari</strong>"  . "a"`, al hacer el `echo` se vería así: m**ari**a.

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción sería buscar dentro de una concatenación de columnas, de esta forma:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from alumno where concat(nombre_alumno, rut_alumno, apellido_alumno) like '%".$b."%' LIMIT 10" ,$con);
```

De esta forma si quieres sumar nuevas columnas dentro de la búsqueda solo bastaría incluirla en la función `contact`